# how to merge my application,database and framework in one exe

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created desktop application using visual studio 2010 (C#) connected with database (sql server 2008).
I want to make my application a setup project to install at any operating system (Xp,VISTA and Windows 7) and at different machines including all files like framework,sql server and database files in one exe.

Please help me i need this necessary
Thank you

Comment: With standard MSI Windows Installer technology, you typically define requirements like the .NET framework and SQL Server, and the installer will download and install the necessary bits off the internet. Most of those installers aren't designed to be "merged" into a single EXE - that would become absolutely **HUGE** - not a good idea!

Comment: thank you but how to add my database files with my application in setup project

Answer (score 0):

An useful answer may be is to make a batch file with all the required software and database. When you start the batch, all the application will install.

Comment: I doubt this answers the question, elaborate and give an example of such batch file